# extract number from json array

Tags: json, react-native, extract

hi I am new to react native and trying to extract the value of **numberOfCalls** from the array(the following picture shows how the array looks like.I try to use data[0].numberOfCalls
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MuyK.png), but it somethings works and somethings do not work, do you have any idea?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MuyK.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MuyK.png): [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MuyK.png)

Comment: This way It will always look for `numberOfCalls` and if It doesn't found then what would be shown? You can do it this way like `data.length > 0 ? data[0].numberOfCalls : 0`

Comment: oh think you, i use this method to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

`data[0].numberOfCalls`
should always return the number of calls. If it doesn't ,console.log(), in those cases you might be getting some different array.